# Put select2 tags to the right

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

I created a tag input using jquery and select2 in the snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#tag-input .js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    placeholder: "Add tag"
  }).on('change', function(e) {
    if($(this).val() && $(this).val().length) {
      $(this).next('.select2-container').find('li.select2-search--inline input.select2-search__field').attr('placeholder', 'Add tag');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.select2-selection {
  height: 36px !important; 
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border: solid 1px #D1D1D1 !important;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.select2-selection--multiple {
  height: 160px !important;
}

.select2-selection__choice__remove {
   float: right;
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 2px;
}

.select2-selection__choice {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-right: 12px !important;
  padding-left: 16px !important;
  background-color: #D0F3FF !important;
  color: #333 !important;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 3px !important;
}

.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #333;
  width: 88px !important;
}

.select2-container {
  
}

.select2-container:hover,
.select2-container:focus,
.select2-container:active,
.select2-selection:hover,
.select2-selection:focus,
.select2-selection:active {
  outline-color: transparent;
  outline-style: none;
}

.select2-results__options li {
  display: block; 
}

.select2-selection__rendered {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.select2-selection__arrow {
  display: none;
}

.select2-results__option--highlighted {
  background-color: #D0F3FF !important;
  color: #333 !important;
}

.select2-selection__choice__remove {
  margin-left: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.select2-dropdown {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15) !important;
  border: none !important;
  margin-top: 4px !important;
}

.select2-results__option {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  padding-left: 8px !important;
}

.selectable-dropdown-each {
  display: block; 
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px !important;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selectable-hover {
  background-color: #D0F3FF;
}

.select2-results__option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1 !important; 
}

.select2-search__field {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 8px !important;
  border-color: #D1D1D1 !important;
}

.select2-selection__placeholder {
  color: #D1D1D1 !important; 
}

.form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
  width: 412px !important;
}

#tag-input .select2-selection--multiple {
  border: none !important;
  height: auto !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#tag-input .select2-selection__rendered {
  padding: 0 !important; 
}

#tag-input .select2-search__field {
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #D0F3FF;
  border: none !important;
  padding-left: 16px !important;
  padding-right: 16px;
  width: 104px !important;
}

#tag-input .select2-search__field::placeholder {
  color: #aaa; 
}

#tag-input .select2-search__field:focus {
  border: solid 1px #00c983 !important;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#tag-input .select2-search__field:focus::placeholder {
  color: #d1d1d1;
}

#tag-input .select2-selection__choice {
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px !important;
}



.form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1302px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.form-row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 32px 0 !important;
}

.form-divided {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-divided-left {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.form-divided-right {
  margin-left: -4px;
  width: 412px;
}

.form-input-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #333;
}

.form-unit {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form-row">
    <div id="tag-input" class="form-unit form-divided form-divided-right">
      <label for="emp-id" class="form-input-label">Tag Input</label>
      <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="a1">Item A1</option>
        <option value="a2">Item A2</option>
        <option value="b1">Item B1</option>
        <option value="a1">Item C1</option>
        <option value="a2">Item C2</option>
        <option value="b1">Item C3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, the input field looks like moving along as the tags inserted. Is there a way to put the inserted tags to the right of the input? So that my input stays to the left of the container.

Can anyone help me in this? Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding code to the `change` function from my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379809/customize-select2-multi-select) to detach the **search `<li>`** and prepending it to the `<ul class="select2-selection__rendered">`, here's the change to keep the input tag on the left and keep moving the selected options to the right.

```
$("#tag-input .js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
  placeholder: "Add tag"
}).on('change', function(e) {
    if($(this).val() && $(this).val().length) {
       var searchItem = $(this).next('.select2-container').find('li.select2-search--inline').detach();

       var renderList = $(this).next('.select2-container').find('ul.select2-selection__rendered').prepend(searchItem);
       searchItem.find('input.select2-search__field').attr('placeholder', 'Add tag');

    }
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#tag-input .js-example-basic-multiple").select2({
    placeholder: "Add tag"
  }).on('change', function(e) {
    if($(this).val() && $(this).val().length) {
     var searchItem = $(this).next('.select2-container').find('li.select2-search--inline').detach();
      
      var renderList = $(this).next('.select2-container').find('ul.select2-selection__rendered').prepend(searchItem);
      searchItem.find('input.select2-search__field').attr('placeholder', 'Add tag');
      
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.select2-selection {
  height: 36px !important; 
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  border: solid 1px #D1D1D1 !important;
  padding-left: 4px;
}

.select2-selection--multiple {
  height: 160px !important;
}

.select2-selection__choice__remove {
   float: right;
   margin-right: 0;
   margin-left: 2px;
}

.select2-selection__choice {
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding-right: 12px !important;
  padding-left: 16px !important;
  background-color: #D0F3FF !important;
  color: #333 !important;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius: 3px !important;
}

.select2-search--inline .select2-search__field {
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #333;
  width: 88px !important;
}

.select2-container {
  
}

.select2-container:hover,
.select2-container:focus,
.select2-container:active,
.select2-selection:hover,
.select2-selection:focus,
.select2-selection:active {
  outline-color: transparent;
  outline-style: none;
}

.select2-results__options li {
  display: block; 
}

.select2-selection__rendered {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.select2-selection__arrow {
  display: none;
}

.select2-results__option--highlighted {
  background-color: #D0F3FF !important;
  color: #333 !important;
}

.select2-selection__choice__remove {
  margin-left: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.select2-dropdown {
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15) !important;
  border: none !important;
  margin-top: 4px !important;
}

.select2-results__option {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 24px !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  padding-left: 8px !important;
}

.selectable-dropdown-each {
  display: block; 
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px !important;
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selectable-hover {
  background-color: #D0F3FF;
}

.select2-results__option[aria-selected="true"] {
  background-color: #f1f1f1 !important; 
}

.select2-search__field {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 8px !important;
  border-color: #D1D1D1 !important;
}

.select2-selection__placeholder {
  color: #D1D1D1 !important; 
}

.form-unit .select2-container, .form-unit .select2-selection {
  width: 412px !important;
}

#tag-input .select2-selection--multiple {
  border: none !important;
  height: auto !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}

#tag-input .select2-selection__rendered {
  padding: 0 !important; 
}

#tag-input .select2-search__field {
  height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background-color: #D0F3FF;
  border: none !important;
  padding-left: 16px !important;
  padding-right: 16px;
  width: 104px !important;
}

#tag-input .select2-search__field::placeholder {
  color: #aaa; 
}

#tag-input .select2-search__field:focus {
  border: solid 1px #00c983 !important;
  background-color: #fff;
}

#tag-input .select2-search__field:focus::placeholder {
  color: #d1d1d1;
}

#tag-input .select2-selection__choice {
  height: 32px;
  line-height: 32px;
  border-radius: 16px !important;
}



.form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1302px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.form-row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 0 32px 0 !important;
}

.form-divided {
  display: inline-block;
}

.form-divided-left {
  margin-right: 32px;
}

.form-divided-right {
  margin-left: -4px;
  width: 412px;
}

.form-input-label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: #333;
}

.form-unit {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.11/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-p2jx59pefphTFIpeqCcISO9MdVfIm4pNnsL08A6v5vaQc4owkQqxMV8kg4Yvhaw/" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="form-row">
    <div id="tag-input" class="form-unit form-divided form-divided-right">
      <label for="emp-id" class="form-input-label">Tag Input</label>
      <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" name="states[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="a1">Item A1</option>
        <option value="a2">Item A2</option>
        <option value="b1">Item B1</option>
        <option value="a1">Item C1</option>
        <option value="a2">Item C2</option>
        <option value="b1">Item C3</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps. :)